# How to get the vocabulary ID of a taxonomy term?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I need to get vocabulary ID by term object.Please see attched screenshot for term object.[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to use the `getVocabularyId()` function on the term object like:

```
$vocabulary_id = $term->getVocabularyId();
```

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/function/Term%3A%3AgetVocabularyId/8.2.x.

Comment: $term->getVocabularyId() is deprecated. Use $term->bundle() instead.

Answer (score 15):

I think we're supposed to use [EntityInterface::bundle](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Abundle/8.4.x) now as [Term::getVocabularyId](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/function/Term%3A%3AgetVocabularyId/8.4.x) is deprecated:

> Scheduled for removal before Drupal 9.0.0. Use TermInterface::bundle()
>   instead.